# Solution to first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the initial value problem $$(3y^2+4y)y'+2x+cosx=0,y(0)=1$$
What I did:
$$(3y^2+4y)y'=-2x-cosx \rightarrow (3y^2+4y)\frac{dy}{dx}=-2x-cosx$$
I now separate the variables and integrate:
$$(3y^2+4y)dy=(-2x-cosx)dx\rightarrow \int(3y^2+4y)dy=\int(-2x-cosx)dx + C$$
$$y^3+2y^2=-x^2-sinx+C$$
At this point using the initial value, yields $C=3$

The equation is $y^3+2y^2=-x^2-sinx+3$

My question is do I have something else to do here? Did I solve this correctly?

Comment: You are done!  Good job!

Comment: You did a good job ! Don't try to go further (except if you enjoy facing monsters !).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you have nothing else to do. Your solution is correct. You won't get an explicit solution $y(x)$ here. Even if you wanted to solve for $y$ (which you could do using the solution to the cubic equation), your solution wouldn't be uniquely determined for all values of $x$. Instead, the solution is given by the curve $y^3 + 2y^2 + x^2 + \sin(x) = 3$.

Comment: Thank you, I was worried I had to give an explicit solution for y.